# Angular mat table- added row doesn't shown after deleting another

Tags: angular

I've created a table which the user can add rows (by pushing)

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
this.ELEMENT_DATA.push(...);
this.table.renderRows();
```

and delete rows (by filtering the data source), those actions work just fine.

```
this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data
      .filter(i => i !== elm)
      .map((i, idx) => (i.position = (idx + 1), i));
```

After deleting one row and adding another, the ELEMENT_DATA array does get the item and the table wont show it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the table detection change strategy is `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, so it means for the showing new item you need to change the array referance

your delete function returns new array with the filtered data array. I think your add function just do `array.push(newItem)`

so you can add a new item in this way. This one should work on your case.

```
this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data, newItem]
```

Comment: Thank you too. glad to help you @almogldbh!